# generic programming in c++ and typedef inside a class

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

let's say I have the following code in A.cpp file:

```
template <typename T>
class A{
   typedef T myType;
   myType foo();
}
```

If I want to implement the foo function in this file , what is the syntax to write the function declaration?
I thought it'll be:

```
template <class T>
myType A<T>::foo(){
.
.
.
}
```

obviously it's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the typedef is only available within the class, and the return type is not in the class:

```
template <class T>
typename A<T>::myType A<T>::foo() {}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer (the checkmark below the vote counter) to make that clear to others.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
typename A<T> :: myType A<T> :: foo ()
{
}
```

Comment: This won't compile on gcc (and all other standard-compliant compilers, I think): You missed a typename.